# How can get new location from below method

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, mkannotation

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
    annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view                  
    didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState 
    fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState
```

Comment: where is accept button ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You an use this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
        annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView 
        didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState 
        fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState 
{
    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D droppedAt = annotationView.annotation.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"dropped at %f,%f", droppedAt.latitude, droppedAt.longitude);
    }
}
```

This will give you the coordinates of the final location when the `MKAnnotationView` is dropped.

Answer (score 0):

You can check against drag state and then using `annotationView.annotation.coordinate.latitude` and `annotationView.annotation.coordinate.latitude` you will get co-ordinates of new location.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState
{

    //if dragging ended
    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone && oldState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding) {

        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        MKCoordinateSpan span;

        span.latitudeDelta = 0.00212872;
        span.longitudeDelta = 0.00212872;

        CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
        location.latitude = annotationView.annotation.coordinate.latitude;
        location.longitude = annotationView.annotation.coordinate.longitude; 
        [self getAddress:location.latitude withLong:location.longitude];

        region.span = span;
        region.center = location;

        if (addAnnotation != nil) {
            [myMap removeAnnotation:addAnnotation];
            [addAnnotation release];
            addAnnotation = nil;
        }

        addAnnotation = [[Annotation alloc] init];
        addAnnotation.coordinate = location;
        [myMap addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
        [myMap setRegion:region animated:YES];
        [myMap regionThatFits:region];
    }

}
```

addAnnotation is object of `Annotation`.